# vbscript get username from mail

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap

It is possible to get the username from active directory by query the email address ? Query the email address by username its no problem like this:

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strUser = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)
strEMail = objUser.mail
```

But in my scenario I have only the email and no username.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it off LDAP directly.

It's faster to create a query and extract exactly what you are after (**sAMAccountName**):

```
UserNameFromEmail "Firstname.Lastname@YourDomain.com"

Sub UserNameFromEmail(sEmail)
    Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2
    Const PageSize = 1000
    Dim sRootLDAP, oConnection, oCommand, oRecordSet

    sRootLDAP = "'LDAP://" & GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE").Get("defaultNamingContext") & "'"

    Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    oConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
    Set oCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set oCommand.ActiveConnection = oConnection
    oCommand.CommandText = "Select sAMAccountName from " & sRootLDAP & " Where mail='" & sEmail & "'"
    oCommand.Properties("Page Size") = PageSize
    oCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
    oCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE
    oCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = True
    Set oRecordSet = oCommand.Execute
    oRecordSet.MoveFirst
    Do Until oRecordSet.EOF
        WScript.Echo "Username for """ & sEmail & """ is """ & oRecordSet.Fields(0) & """"
        oRecordSet.MoveNext
    Loop
    Set oRecordSet = Nothing
    Set oCommand = Nothing
    Set oConnection = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Its also possible to make a full text search? For example search any field for "asdf" ? Thank you in advance

Comment: You can search all attributes of an AD object, just that some attributes are not text based, some are dates, binary, collection, etc.