# IISADMPWD change password with e-mail

Tags: email, active-directory, passwords, change-password

We use IISADMPWD webapplication to allow users to change their AD account password.

Some of our AD accounts dont have the same UPN as mail, but we are changing that for the new users. So the new users now have the same on both UPN and mail.

Can I some how add or modify IISADMPWD so it accept users e-mailaddress when changing password?

Today it only works with UPN,

1. is it possible to replace the attributes in the code to support mail instead?
2. or perhaps add a feature to "search for users with this mail"?
3. or search for user by mail and then get the users UPN to continue changing password?

I believe the development of this feature should be made in the achg.asp file
https://github.com/sysboss/IISADMPWD/blob/master/iisadmpwd/achg.asp

Can anyone help me with this?

Sincerely
Fredrik

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843380/vbscript-get-username-from-mail

Comment: But dont know how to run that vbscript in .asp

Comment: This ended with me using this instead https://ltb-project.org/documentation/self-service-password